# GitHub Actions taking too much time to just build the entire solution

Tags: vb.net, github, build, msbuild, github-actions

So working on VB.net project and trying to build the solution using GitHub Actions.

My job is simple as below

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\"
             .\MSBuild.exe ./MyProject.sln
```

It starts building the solution process but it takes too much time. (Not mentioning specific time as it's still running over last 6 hours)

Action continuously writing the log and it stick to this message,

```
CompileLicxFiles:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\lc.exe /target:MyProject.Dll
```

Not sure, if I need to register a DLL or install a third party software to have references on windows agent.

Please help or guide me what I could be doing wrong over here.

Comment: Can you share logs?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej - thanks for looking at. after analyzing the logs it seems like, it's hanging the process after printing *CompileLicxFiles:* and some third party DLL I am using in the project. Do I need to install the third party software on windows agent first?

Comment: Well if they are not provided with your app then yes.

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofMadej, actually all required DLLs are already there in project. Could there be any other reason?